# Unable to listen change event in controller

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, event-listener

Am new in Ext JS community. Here I want to apply a change event to child component which is 'textfield'.
I have specified the 'onChangeSealNumber' function in the controller. But it's not getting fired.
Can someone help me into it?

I have tried many approaches, however, If I pass anonymous function on change, it will work. But it won't work when we explicitly specify as 'onChangeSealNumber'.

**View File**

```
/**
 * Search Form Panel View.
 * @class 'BulkTransaction.view.searchfrom.SearchForm'
 */

Ext.define('BulkTransaction.view.searchform.SearchForm', {

  extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

  requires: [
    'Common.view.widget.RepeatingWidgetGroup',
    'BulkTransaction.view.storagelocation.StorageLocation',
    'BulkTransaction.view.searchform.SearchFormController',
  ],

  alias: 'widget.searchform',

  controller: 'searchformcontroller',

  items: [
    {
      xtype: 'basepanel',
      width: '100%',
      reference: 'searchform',
      header: false,
      items: [
        {
          width: '100%',
          xtype: 'connect-repeating-widget-group',
          bind: {
            store: '{topSealNumbers}'
          },
          bindReference: 'topSealNumbers',
          widgetConfig: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: BulkTransaction.util.Constants.searchForm.topSealNumbers,
            allowBlank: false,
            bind: '{topSealNumbers.searchCriteria}',
            cls: 'seal-number-field',
            listeners: {
              change: 'onChangeSealNumber'
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

**Controler File**

```
/** 
 * Controller containing the methods implementing functionality 
 * related to search form
*/
Ext.define('BulkTransaction.view.searchform.SearchFormController', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
  alias: 'controller.searchformcontroller',
  init: function () {
      const me = this;
      const viewModel = me.getViewModel();
      viewModel.bind({
        bindTo: '{topSealNumbers}',
        deep: true
      }, me.onSearchCriteriaChange, me);
  },
  /**
   * Handle change to the sealnumber details
   * @private
   */
  onSearchCriteriaChange: function (store) {
    const me = this;
    let searchCriteriaRecords;
    searchCriteriaRecords = store.queryBy(rec =>{
      if (!Ext.isEmpty(rec.get('searchCriteria').trim())) {
        return rec;
      }
    });

    this.fireEvent('toggleSearchButton', searchCriteriaRecords.length > 0);

  },

  onSealNumberChange (elm) {
    const me = this,
    view = me.getView();
  }

});
```

Comment: Looking at your code in your change listener you are calling `onChangeSealNumber`, but in your controller there's no `onChangeSealNumber` function

Comment: @MatheusHatje My bad. Updated the code accordingly. But the issue is still there. Is there anything to do with binding? Not sure.

Comment: @MatheusHatje If you check the controller file, I have already created 'onSearchCriteriaChange' function. It's working as expected, but when I clear the 'textfield', it's not getting trigged. So I have decided to trigger 'onChangeSealNumber' manually when field is empty.

Answer (score 1):

In you controller you need to create a function named `onChangeSealNumber` something like this

```
Ext.define('BulkTransaction.view.searchform.SearchFormController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.searchformcontroller',
    onChangeSealNumber: function(field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
        //do something here

    },
})
```

Comment: what you are tryinng to do? can you put a console.log in the onChangeSealNumber function to make sure the fuction is being called?

Comment: I have already tried by putting debugger inside 'onChangeSealNumber ' function. Basically what I trying to do is, when the seal number gets changed, the store should get updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try (MyApp - name of your application): 
`listeners: {change: MyApp.app.getController('SearchFormController').onChangeSealNumber()}` 
But as for me its not good way to work with controller. More better add into controller (inside init):

```
init: function (application) {  
  this.control({
    "searchform textfield": {
      change: this.onChangeSealNumber
    },
  });
}
```

As for identifier I'm not sure because as usually use itemId and name

```
(like    `"#myItemId textfield[name=MyFieldName]"`    )
```